# C# Webkit won't display Html

Tags: c#, html, webkit

I've included the **WebkitBrowser** from **WebKit.Net** into my C# Project and it works as it should, except when I want to load a Html **string**. Here is the Html I want to display:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=2">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>mentor+</title>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.Application/css/style-ver-1463736306000.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.Application/css/landingpage-ver-1463664722000.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.Application/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min-ver-1448702160000.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.Application/vis/vis.min-ver-1460038992000.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./wicket/resource/de.agilecoders.wicket.webjars.request.resource.WebjarsCssResourceReference/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-ver-1455709722000.css" />
</head>
    <body>
    <div>

    </div>

<div>
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="bs-example">

        <div class="jumbotron">

            <div id="mynetwork" ></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
    <footerbucket><script type="text/javascript" src="./wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.resource.JQueryResourceReference/jquery/jquery-1.12.0-ver-1457005336000.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior/res/js/wicket-event-jquery-ver-1457005336000.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.Application/js/topButton-ver-1462984064000.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.Application/js/jquery-1-12-1-min-ver-1462366394000.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.Application/vis/vis.min-ver-1463655366000.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.Application/js/networkgraph-ver-1463047612000.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./wicket/resource/de.agilecoders.wicket.core.markup.html.references.JQueryMigrateJavaScriptReference/js/jquery-migrate-1.3.0-ver-1457345416000.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="bootstrap-js" src="./wicket/resource/de.agilecoders.wicket.webjars.request.resource.WebjarsJavaScriptResourceReference/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap-ver-1455709722000.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
/*<![CDATA[*/
Wicket.Event.add(window, "load", function(event) { 
createNetwork(new vis.DataSet([{"id":0,"label":"Amalie","color":"#FA5858"},{"id":1,"label":"Daniel","color":"#2E64FE","shape":"box"},{"id":2,"label":"Carola","color":"#01DF01","shape":"ellipse"},{"id":3,"label":"Annette","color":"#58FAF4","shape":"ellipse"},{"id":4,"label":"Marius","color":"#58FAF4","shape":"box"}]),new vis.DataSet([{"id":0,"from":0,"to":1,"length":80,"width":6,"color":"#2E64FE"},{"id":1,"from":0,"to":2,"length":40,"width":6,"color":"#01DF01"},{"id":2,"from":0,"to":3,"length":40,"width":6,"color":"#58FAF4"},{"id":3,"from":0,"to":4,"length":40,"width":6,"color":"#58FAF4"}]));
;});
/*]]>*/
</script>
</footerbucket>
</html>
</body>
```

I used this with Cefsharp with the serveraddress and it worked:

```
ChromiumWebBrowser cef = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
cef.LoadHtml(responseFromServer, server + "home");
```

As you can see, one parameter was the serveraddress.

If i export the Html-string into a file and try to load it with any Browser, it is not working either, so I think the server address needs to be provided, but I can't find any fitting method. Please can you help me?

## EDIT:

Now I edited the code from the server that it is going to work with POST parameters and it works in every Browser. Except WebKit!

The URL now looks like this:

```
http://mentorplus.de/networkgenerator/getNetworkgraph?network=[{%22focusPerson%22:%22Amalie%22,%22memberList%22:[{%22role%22:%22MENTOR%22,%22name%22:%22Daniel%22,%22gender%22:%22MALE%22,%22relationship%22:%22FRIENDS%22,%22emotionalRelationship%22:%22NORMAL%22,%22distance%22:%22TWOHOUR%22},{%22role%22:%22MENTOR%22,%22name%22:%22Carola%22,%22gender%22:%22FEMALE%22,%22relationship%22:%22FAMILY%22,%22emotionalRelationship%22:%22NORMAL%22,%22distance%22:%22ONEHOUR%22},{%22role%22:%22NETWORKMEMBER%22,%22name%22:%22Annette%22,%22gender%22:%22FEMALE%22,%22relationship%22:%22OTHER%22,%22emotionalRelationship%22:%22NORMAL%22,%22distance%22:%22ONEHOUR%22},{%22role%22:%22NETWORKMEMBER%22,%22name%22:%22Marius%22,%22gender%22:%22MALE%22,%22relationship%22:%22OTHER%22,%22emotionalRelationship%22:%22NORMAL%22,%22distance%22:%22ONEHOUR%22}]}]&authenticated=tellur
```

So what's exactly the problem of WebKit? Maybe the scripts?

## EDIT 2:

Interesting, using the Standard Wpf Browser works. So i mark this thread as answered, but I am still interested in the solution

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using the WebKit.NET project?

Comment: Yes I do, sorry, forgot to mention

Comment: So, you're trying to load a static HTML string with a server address specified so that all the javascript, stylesheets and other stuff referenced in the HTML come from the server? And now you'd like to do the same using WebKit.NET? Just to make sure we're on the same page here.

Comment: Exactly, I get the Html code from the server itself via a request and everything is stored on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a direct way to do that using [WebKitBrowser](https://github.com/webkitdotnet/webkitdotnet/blob/5a67dae661c15f9da92ec57f13ff3f83d4c8a402/WebKitBrowser/WebKitBrowser.cs) from [WebKit.NET](https://github.com/webkitdotnet/webkitdotnet/). However, it should be possible to load an HTML string by jumping through a few loops.

Internally, the [WebKitBrowserCore](https://github.com/webkitdotnet/webkitdotnet/blob/develop/WebKitCore/WebKitBrowserCore.cs) class uses a call to `_webView.mainFrame().loadHTMLString(Text, null)` in the `DocumentText` property's set method. That confirms that at least some sort of HTML loading is possible internally. However, this method is in the native WebKit WebView, so you need to modify the project to get access to it.

I'd create a fork of the project and do the following changes.

1. Add a new method to `WebKitBrowserCore` called LoadHTMLString with two parameters for HTML string, and server address.
2. Call the `_webView.mainFrame().loadHTMLString(html, server);` method with the parameters.
3. Expose the `LoadHTMLString` method to [WebKitBrowser](https://github.com/webkitdotnet/webkitdotnet/blob/5a67dae661c15f9da92ec57f13ff3f83d4c8a402/WebKitBrowser/WebKitBrowser.cs) class the same way as others like for example Navigate method (it just calls the core's Navigate method.

I can't test this right now, so I'm not entirely sure if the internal loadHTMLString method of WebView works as intended.

**Edit:** Looks like you could also use the `GetWebView` method in WebKitBrowser, to call the `mainFrame().loadHTMLString()` method directly like this (syntax might be incorrect but you'll figure it out):

```
(IWebView)webKitBrowser.GetWebView()).mainFrame().loadHTMLString(html, server);
```

**Edit 2:** I just realized that WebKit is an open source project and it's easy to verify that loadHTMLString does what I think it does. Here's an excerpt from the WebFrame.h header file:

```
/*!
    @method loadHTMLString:baseURL:
    @param string The string to use for the main page of the document.
    @param URL The base URL to apply to relative URLs within the document.
    - (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)URL;
*/

HRESULT loadHTMLString([in] BSTR string, [in] BSTR baseURL);
```

That's the exact method you need to call and is the method CEFSharp calls internally.

Comment: Okay, I'll try your first two answers, but I couldn't find any method **loadHTMLString** inside the WebKitBrowser class, so I think I have to rewrite this directly inside the source, correct?


**EDIT**: Your first Edit throws a **HRESULT E_FAIL** Error

Comment: @DanielDirtyNativeMartin Correct, you need to go through points 1 to 3 to expose `loadHTMLString` from core to the WebKitBrowser class.

Comment: @DanielDirtyNativeMartin I still think it should be possible to use my first edit as a solution, but there could be something weird going on. I'll need to try if I can get it to work. Forking the project and modifying the source is so much more work so it would be nice to get it to work with the existing functionality.

Comment: I am also trying to edit the source of WebKit, but I get more and more errors. Maybe there is really an easier way of doing what I need, and I would be very graceful if you find one